# How can I remap enter key on MacOS big sur?

Tags: macos, big-sur, keybindings

my enter key broke and doesn't work, can I rebind the Enter key to work with RSHIFT instead of enter?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're gunna need some software for that. My only recommendation to give a shot is Karabiner Elements https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

Comment: karabiner didn't work

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you tried to solve it with Karabiner and how it didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 2):

Try Karabiner

https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

Although it says it's compatible with M1 macs, I dont know if it's ARM native or runs through Rosetta2. Any app that runs through Rosetta 2 thrashes the SSD with lots of writes (at least 4x more than M! native apps) Too much writing to your SSD can lead to senility of the SSD. The only solution to this is to avoid running non native apps through Rosetta2 (which makes  memory resident apps like Google chrome a problem)

Comment: If I asked about the "rosetta apps thrash" do you have some insight / measures on that? I'm not seeing that at all, but lots of people are saying things like that. +1 for the Karabiner link - that and hammerspoon seem to be the heavy weights for keybinding changes / automation.

Comment: Is it safe to use Karabiner where does it capture our typings and send them to their servers?